# TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I'm currently following the tutorial and kept getting the error above. Checked the source code of the project and nothing seemed to be wrong.
I'm a just a beginner so I've haven't tried anything to change the code as I don't know much; only went as far as to search up the error but got nothing.

The fetch error is at the bottom of this code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextField, Button, Grid, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class RoomJoinPage extends Component { 

    constructor(props) { 
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            roomCode: "",
            error: ""
        }

        this._handleTextFieldChange = this._handleTextFieldChange.bind(this);
        this._roomButtonPressed = this._roomButtonPressed.bind(this)
    }

    render() { 
        return (
        <Grid container spacing={1} align="center">
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Typography component='h4' variant='h4'>
                    Join a Room
                </Typography>
                </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TextField
                    error = {this.state.error}
                    label = "Code"
                    placeholder = "Enter a Room Code"
                    value = {this.state.roomCode}
                    halperText = {this.state.error}
                    variant = "outlined" 
                    onChange = { 
                        this._handleTextFieldChange
                    }
                />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                 <Button variant = "contained" color = "primary" to = "/" onClick = 
{this._roomButtonPressed}>
                    Enter Code
                </Button>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Button variant = "contained" color = "secondary" to = "/" component = {Link}>
                    Back
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        );
    }

    _handleTextFieldChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            roomCode: e.target.value
        })
    }
```

Fetch error:

```
    _roomButtonPressed() {
        const requestOptions = {
            methods: "POST", 
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                code: this.state.roomCode,
            }),
        };
        fetch("/api/join-room", requestOptions)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                this.props.history.push(`/room/${this.state.roomCode}`)
            } else {
                this.setState({error: "Room not found."})
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not methods but method attribute

Comment: Use `method: "POST"` instead

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that fetch is asynchronous, so you have to declare that in your code. You can use `async` and `await` to do that.

```
  async _roomButtonPressed() {
        const requestOptions = {
            methods: "POST", 
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                code: this.state.roomCode,
            }),
        };
        await fetch("/api/join-room", requestOptions)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                this.props.history.push(`/room/${this.state.roomCode}`)
            } else {
                this.setState({error: "Room not found."})
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```